# AttributeError: module 'botocore' has no attribute 'session' when following the boto3 quickstart

Tags: python, boto3, aws-cli, botocore

I was following the boto3 quickstart instructions and I can run `import boto3`, but when I try to execute any basic command like `db = boto3.resource('dynamodb')` I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-144-424c27c1bae1>", line 1, in <module>
    botocore.session.get_session()

AttributeError: module 'botocore' has no attribute 'session'
```

The credentials and config files look good and i tried to reinstall awscli and boto3 but is not helping. I don't understand what is the issue.

Comment: both awscli and boto3 installed using `pip install`

Comment: Can you provide full example code? Also are you running this on some linux distro?

Answer (score 3):

```
from botocore.session import Session

session = Session()
```

use above code instead of using

```
session = botocore.session.get_session()
```

botocore 1.19.57 documentation https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html#how-do-i-update-my-code

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this does not work.

```
import boto3

boto3.resource('dynamodb')
```

But this works.

```
from botocore.session import Session

session = Session()
session.create_client("ec2", aws_access_key_id=<access_key_id>, aws_secret_access_key=<secret_access_key>)
```